# Using node modules with Rollup to build web client

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, package.json, rollupjs

I'm trying to build a react application using rollup instead of browserify and babel. I realize I need to use the `rollup-plugin-babel` to transpile jsx, but when I tell rollup the format is `iife`, the final page loads with an error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined`

What do I need to add to the `rollup.config.js` to include the node modules I've installed in `package.json` in my final build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

1. Include React as a separate `<script>` tag before your app bundle
2. Include [rollup-plugin-node-resolve](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-node-resolve) in your config file, to pull in dependencies from your `node_modules` folder.

If you take the second route you'll also need [rollup-plugin-commonjs](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs) (to convert the CommonJS module into an ES module). I *think* you would also need to add `import * as React from 'react'` to each module that contained JSX, otherwise you'll continue to get the ReferenceError.

Note: you might be able to use [rollup-plugin-buble](https://gitlab.com/Rich-Harris/rollup-plugin-buble) to transpile JSX. It's similar to the Babel plugin but much faster (though it doesn't transpile every ES2015 feature)